# label did not show out

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

This is how my interface looks like in Android Studio:

[image]

This is my interface look like in a real device:

[image]

**Why the label did not show out and I can't even change the `EditText` background color?**

Here are some of my code XML file, for the below part I'm using `ScrollView` and the color part I'm using Relative layout. Both of these layouts are in a `CardView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/card_view"

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="235dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/transparent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/transparent">


            <studio.carbonylgroup.textfieldboxes.TextFieldBoxes
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:labelText="Email"
                app:hasClearButton="true">

                <studio.carbonylgroup.textfieldboxes.ExtendedEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:id="@+id/input_email"/>

            </studio.carbonylgroup.textfieldboxes.TextFieldBoxes>



        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/transparent">

            <studio.carbonylgroup.textfieldboxes.TextFieldBoxes
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:labelText="Username"
                app:hasClearButton="true">

                <studio.carbonylgroup.textfieldboxes.ExtendedEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/input_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            </studio.carbonylgroup.textfieldboxes.TextFieldBoxes>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if u need more info pls tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice below lines:

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...

    app:labelText="Username"  //app is a tool namespace, so label text only shown in preview
```

Modify to:

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...

    app:labelText="Username"
```

Comment: after i modify it, the app crash and i getting this error:
android resource linking failed

Comment: so how can i fix this:
app:labelText="Username"  //app is a tool namespace, so label text only shown in preview

Comment: @Choy In my answer, I gave the modification.

Comment: u means copy this into my textfieldbox?

Comment: @Choy Find xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools" in your old xml file, and replace it with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: the app will crash

Comment: i copy :   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" put it into each textfieldbox and it works

Comment: @Choy glad to hear you solve it , if helpful to you, could you upvote or accept my answer? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable.xml file and set it to your edittext background like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:width="4sp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</shape> 


    <studio.carbonylgroup.textfieldboxes.ExtendedEditText
                android:id="@+id/et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable"
   />
```

add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in your TextFieldBoxes